# How do I find a name in a range in Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am creating a Google Sheet that helps to organize students and sends emails to the appropriate parties. Part of this is finding a student's advisor.

Currently, I have two tabs, one with a list of students with their advisor and another with a list of all the students. I am trying to make a function on the student list that will search the advisory sheet and return the name of their advisor. All names are identically written between the two tabs, so "Jane Doe" on one would not be written "Doe, Jane" on the other. As far as strings go, "Jane Doe" == "Jane Doe" between the tabs.

Here is a link to a smaller, [fake version of the real spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1z3WB4ZzQ6WJG-nYMdgZy7SgZ-YSS0GpM46EjLYER0Pg/edit?usp=sharing)

TIA

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, 
 SPLIT(FLATTEN(Advisories!A2:D&"♦"&Advisories!A1:D1), "♦"), 2, 0)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create a custom function below. Using standard functions would be too complicated.
After you paste this code to you script editor and save, place the formula `={"Advisor";mylookup(A2:A,Advisories!$A$1:$C)}` to the B1 cell

```
function myLookup(students, advisorsStudents) {
  const advisors = advisorsStudents[0]
  const studentsData = advisorsStudents.slice(1) 
  const assignedAdvisors = students.map(student=>{
    if(student==""){
      return ""
    }
    const rowFound = studentsData.find(row=>row.find(x=>x==student))
    if(rowFound){
      const index = rowFound.findIndex(x=>x==student)  
      return advisors[index]
    } else{
      return "advisor not found"
    }
  })
  return assignedAdvisors.map(a=>[a])
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Give a try on below formula

```
=ArrayFormula(INDEX(Advisories!$A$1:$C$1,,MAX((Advisories!$A$2:$C$4=A2)*(COLUMN(Advisories!$A$2:$C$4)))))
```

[image]